# Make a query with DISTINCT clause run faster

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have the following query:

```
select distinct type, account 
  from balances_tbl 
 where month = 'DEC-12'
```

The table `balances_tbl` has over 3 million records per month. The distinct type and account rows are maybe around 20,000 records. The `month` column is indexed. The `type` and `account` columns are also indexed. The query takes a really long time (about 30 minutes) to execute.

Is there a way to make this query with the `DISTINCT` clause faster?

Comment: Please post the results of EXPLAIN PLAN of the select query above, as it'll help the Oracle gurus on SO help you out.

Comment: Does someone really need to sift through 20k records?

Comment: How many months' worth of data does your table hold?

Comment: It sounds like your database isn't necessarily properly normalised... What is your table structure; you might to be able to improve it?

Comment: **Add the PLAN!!!!!!!** Is it doing a full table scan? Anything else such as  the servers age, performance or traffic? There is not much info to go  on.

Comment: Did anything below help?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add an index that has all three columns.  I would suggest an index on (month, type, account).  That way, Oracle can do its work just by scanning the index.

Otherwise, you have to do a full table scan and then the work for finding just the distinct values.

I might also suggest partitioning the table by month.  However, that would require reorganizing the table and would be much more work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check with your DBA that you have fresh statistics for that table / indexes.

Then, 30 minutes is *too long* for that query, Without seeing the `EXPLAIN PLAN`, I guess Oracle is doing a full scan, so it is visiting every row in the table. Given that there are ~ 3 million rows per month, that might probably be a lot of rows. As you say that `month` is indexed, you can try forcing index access on `month` with:

```
select /*+ index(b <index_on_month)>*/ distinct type, account 
from balances_tbl b
where month = 'DEC-12'
```

where `<index_on_month>` is the name of the index on the `month` column. As it is a date-related field, chances are that the index has a good [clustering factor](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1032431852141).

Anyway, without seeing the execution plan it is very hard to determine why it is taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

you can create Month wise partion or use can use the oracle optimization Hints for faster retrieval of data

these are the hints which 'll useful for ur query

```
 1) /*+ ALL_ROWS */
 2) /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ 
 3) /*+ parallel */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an aggregate function and **ensure there is an index on the month column**. I shouldn't take this long unless the server is a poor one.

Try:

```
select type, 
       account,
       count(*) as dummy
from   balances_tbl 
where  month = 'DEC-12'
group by type,
       account
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the simplest solution - no need for indexes, plans and all this ... :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D, scott.emp E WHERE D.deptno = E.deptno
/  
-- Same as Distinct --
SELECT deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM scott.emp E WHERE E.deptno = D.deptno)
/
```